# AWS IAM Policies for pushing llogs to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a ubuntu ec2 with cloudwatch agent running. The agent is able to push the logs to Cloudwatch as expected. But I am unable to export the logs to S3.

The instance policy has SSMManagedInstanceCore and CloudwatchAgentServerPolicy as described in the documentation.

At this point, I am not sure what policy needs to be assigned.

I also added log policy to write to S3 bucket.

All this is being done in terraform.

Can someone help me solve this pls?
Thanks.

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Any progress or still fully unresolved?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I remember working with the S3:Put and got it working in the past. I am not sure what settings have been changed. Using cron for the export of logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to your instance role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::/<your-bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Depending on the bucket setup, other permissions may be required, e.g. for KMS encryption.

UPDATE

If you want to **automatically** export your logs from CloudWatch Logs to S3 you have to setup [Subscription Filter with Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample). This is fully independent from your instance role and the instance itself.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.

My instance_policy has this and other as required. 

When I do the export logs from cloudwatch to S3 it works but I want it to be seamless.

I also checked that I have the access to s3 bucket from the instance.

Comment: @msg I don't understand what does it mean "seamless" in your case. Also exporting from CW to S3 is not related to your instance role at all.

Comment: What I meant by seamless is without me exporting the data manually.

The instance_profile policy allows the write permission to bucket.

Comment: @mgs I updated the answer with the info of what should be done.

Comment: Quick clarification Marcin. Is there no other way with just the instance_profile and s3 without introducing kinesis here.

Comment: @mgs You could create a bash script which would run in cron and upload your log files directly to s3. I'm not aware of any other automated way provided by aws.

Comment: I used a crontab to do the job. Can't seem to understand why the policy won't send logs to S3.